# I am trying to decide which SPSS test I should use for my research- pre post questionnaire after intervention with 2 different groups

Tags: anova, t-test, spss

I have 2 participant groups Parents and teachers, both completing the same intervention (2 hour educational lesson) From the data I need to compare the answers of both groups to see this impacts on the success of the intervention.
The pre/ post questionnaires included multiple choice questions on different healthy eating behaviours e.g. how many portions of protein should you have per day, and also questions about their own health behaviour. The pre questionnaire takes place before the intervention, the post is 6 weeks after the intervention took place- has it significantly changed the knowledge and behaviours of each group. I'm thinking it maybe a t-test or possibly an ANOVA but I'm getting confused. Can any body please help.

Answer (score 1):

To include both aspects mentioned here (groups and pre-post), you'd need to move beyond a t test to either an ANCOVA (analysis of covariance) model where pre-test is used as a covariate along with the grouping factor (parents/teachers) in predicting the post-test score, or a between-by-within 2x2 ANOVA, where pre-post and post-test are treated as the two levels of a within-subjects factor, with group (parents/teachers) a between-subjects factor.

For the former, you'd use Analyze>General Linear Model>Univariate, with group as a fixed factor, while for the latter you'd use Analyze>General Linear Model>Repeated Measures, specifying one within-subjects factor in the initial dialog and in the main dialog specifying the grouping factor and pre and post-test scores as the within-subjects variables.

The two analyses answer different questions. Looking at the interaction effect in the repeated-measures ANOVA addresses the question of whether or not the groups differ in the pre-to-post change in means, while the ANCOVA model group comparison adjusted for the pre-test covariate addresses the question of equality of post-test group means conditional upon the same pre-test means.

Comment: +1. But it would be helpful if you point out what are the differences and similarities in the two ways (models, the RM and the split-plot) you describe. When one should prefer one and when the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare questionnaire scores before and after the intervention, within a single group, you may want to use a paired-samples t-test. T-tests compare 'pairs' of values; so 'before' and 'after', OR 'group 1' and 'group 2'.

If you want to compare questionnaire scores before and after the intervention, but also between groups (that is, before vs. after AND parents vs. teachers), then go with the ANOVA.